# Mass Spectrometer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Say, we have a mass spectrometer and we want to determine the mass ratio of Hydrogen and Deuterium. Suppose the ions are positively charged and $q=1.6 \times 10^{-19}C$. The magnetic field can be set to $3$ Tesla and the electric potential can be set up to $10^3V$. The radius of the spectrometer has an accuracy of $1mm$. Determine the radius of the spectrometer such that we can distinguish $H^1$ and $H^2$

My attempt: $$m_p=\frac{qB^2r_p^2}{2V}$$ $$m_H=\frac{qB^2r_h^2}{2V}$$ $$r_p-r_H=1mm$$

But, then I have $3$ equations and $4$ unknowns. Then I looked at the solution:

$$m = \frac{qr^2B^2}{2V} \rightarrow \frac{\sigma_m}{m}=\frac{2 \sigma_r}{r} \ \ \rightarrow \ r=2\sigma_r \frac{m} {\sigma_m}=2mm$$

What is $\sigma_r, \sigma_m$ and how did they come up with this?

I've been staring at this for 2 hours, still don't know how... I thought maybe $\sigma_m$ is the mass for Deuterium, but the equation doesn't balance...

Answer (score 2):

"The solution", wherever it's from, should define its notation, but it seems obvious to me that $\sigma_m = m_p - m_H$ and $\sigma_r = r_p - r_H$, as $\sigma_r$ is a common notation for error/uncertainty/accuracy in the quantity $r$.

This must be the case because the equation whose origin puzzles you, follows directly from applying standard [propagation of uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) to

$$m = \frac{qr^2 B^2}{2V}$$

and the uncertainties $\sigma_r$ and $\sigma_m$.